# Reshaping numpy array containing image data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:
all_data=(10000,3072) where each cell in array is data of a 32*32*3 image. When the data in the cell is formatted as:

```
np.transpose(np.reshape(image_data,(3, 32,32)), (1,2,0))
```

the real image is displayed (using plt.imshow or any such libraries)
. Now i want to transform all_data such that the shape of all_data is (10000,32,32,3)
How can i do this?

Comment: what is `image_data`? Is it the same as `all_data` or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, (the same reshaping process but keep the first dimension untouched):

```
all_data.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1)
```

---

*Example*:

```
all_data = np.arange(24).reshape(2,12)
```

Target reshape it to (2,2,2,3):

```
all_data
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

Reshape one element of the data:

```
all_data[0].reshape(3,2,2).transpose(1,2,0)
# array([[[ 0,  4,  8],
#         [ 1,  5,  9]],

#        [[ 2,  6, 10],
#         [ 3,  7, 11]]])
```

Reshape it all together:

```
all_data.reshape(2,3,2,2).transpose(0,2,3,1)[0]
# array([[[ 0,  4,  8],
#         [ 1,  5,  9]],

#        [[ 2,  6, 10],
#         [ 3,  7, 11]]])
```